# Create a hook when a bluetooth device is connected to PulseAudio

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth, pulse-audio

I've set up an A2DP sink on my RaspberryPi 3 with Raspbian on it using the bluetooth plugins for PulseAudio.

Now I wish to hook into the process after a device connects to the sink and run a script right then to do other things like displaying the connected name on some external screen or letting the Pi say on the loudspeakers which device just connected.

Is that generally possible or do I need to find a workaround with something like polling bluetoothctl?

Answer (score 1):

You can get notifications from Pulseaudio via dbus. An example how to do this in python can be found in [pulseaudio-dlna](https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna).

Comment: I'd love to mark this as correct, but that is a fairly complex example, and not really a spot-on answer for my question (not to mention that iirc excerpts of externally linked content should be included)

Comment: It's perfectly fine to write your own answer that shows what you actually did and what code you used, and then accept that. Answers can be improved upon (and if the answer helped you, I wouldn't mind an upvote. :-)